# What techniques are there to allow multiple threads in a tkinter program?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I found this simple Hello World tkinter program:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.hi_there = tk.Button(self)
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Hello World\n(click me)"
        self.hi_there["command"] = self.say_hi
        self.hi_there.pack(side="top")

        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                              command=self.master.destroy)
        self.quit.pack(side="bottom")

    def say_hi(self):
        print("hi there, everyone!")
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Hello World\n(click me again)"

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

What if I want to have the `say_hi()` method perform a long running task and occasionally update the GUI in the mean time?

If I try this:

```
    def say_hi(self):
        print("hi there, everyone!")
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Hello World\n(wait...)"

        sleep(2)  # pretend to do something long-running

        self.hi_there["text"] = "Hello World\n(click me again)"
```

Then the GUI locks up during the sleep and I never see the button change to: `Hello World\n(wait...)`

Comment: if you add `root.update()` before `sleep` then you see this text on button.

Comment: @furas This is an example, but there could be multiple updates needed to the GUI all the while expecting the GUI to be lively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is the modified `Application` class below which uses a `queue` and a new method `poll()` as a message pump to action items of code that the `Thread` wishes to run.

```
from time import sleep
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.queue = Queue()
        self.poll()        

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.hi_there = tk.Button(self)
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Hello World\n(click me)"
        self.hi_there["command"] = self.start_hi
        self.hi_there.pack(side="top")

        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                              command=self.master.destroy)
        self.quit.pack(side="bottom")

    def say_hi(self):
        def do_wait():
            self.hi_there["text"] = "Hello World\n(wait...)"
        def do_again():
            self.hi_there["text"] = "Hello World\n(click me again)"

        print("hi there, everyone!")
        self.queue.put(do_wait)
        sleep(2)  # pretend to do something long-running
        self.queue.put(do_again)

    def start_hi(self):
        thread = Thread(target = self.say_hi)
        thread.start()

    def poll(self):
        if not self.queue.empty():
            item = self.queue.get()
            item()
        self.master.after(100, self.poll)
```

If you use this version of the class then you will notice that the `hi_there Button` releases and the text on the button changes to `wait...` as expected.

*caveat emptor:* This code also allows you to create lots of `Thread` instances, but the `poll()` method only polls every 100mS

Comment: There are rare edge cases where even this approach isn't going to save you. Look at [this](https://pastebin.com/PzmbBVH8). By slightly modifying `create_widgets` and `say_hi`, I can make python crash. The problem is that the last reference to `self` is deleted when `say_hi` finishes so the garbage collector deletes `self` from the second thread, causing `tkinter` to panic and crash.