# Function called before a thread starts, is executing after the thread finishes? why?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, os.system

I want some code to execute and make my UI (I'm using Tkinter) become disabled for the user while a command (youtube-dl) is executing. This UI disabling code is called before the thread, which contains a call to a youtube-dl command, is started, but the UI disabling code doesn't execute until after the thread finishes, and it doesn't even execute correctly... Am I misunderstanding threads?

Here I have my button defined with the call to a function on press:

```
process_video = Button(
    root, 
    text="Get Video", 
    fg="Black",bg="light Blue", 
    command= lambda : videoButtonPress()
)
```

Here is the function being called by the button, where I have my thread starting. I call the function, *Loading(True)* to disable the UI, then I start the thread, then wait using join, then *loading(False)* to re-enable the UI.

```py
def videoButtonPress():
    t = threading.Thread(target=runYTDL_video, args=(urlText.get("1.0","end-1c"), time_mode_button.cget('text'), time_start_text.get("1.0","end-1c"), time_end_text.get("1.0","end-1c")))
    loading(True)
    t.start()
    t.join()
    loading(False)
```

Here is the code being executed by the thread:

```py
def runYTDL_video(url):
    dir = os.getcwd()
    
    os.system("youtube-dl " + url)

    os.chdir(dir)
```

Here is the function to disable/enable the UI elements I have:

```py
def loading(state):
    if(state == True):
        urlText.delete("1.0","end")
        urlText.insert("1.0","LOADING, please wait...")
        urlText.config(bg='grey')
        time_mode_button["state"] = DISABLED
        process_audio["state"] = DISABLED
        process_video["state"] = DISABLED
        urlText.config(state=DISABLED)
        
    else:
        urlText.delete("1.0","end")
        time_mode_button["state"] = NORMAL
        process_audio["state"] = NORMAL
        process_video["state"] = NORMAL
        urlText.config(state=NORMAL)
        urlText.config(bg='white')
```

Comment: Effectively your `videoButtonPress()` function blocks for its entire runtime. This way, `tkinter` will not perform any GUI updates while this function is running.

Comment: See my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59327160/what-techniques-are-there-to-allow-multiple-threads-in-a-tkinter-program)

Comment: It never makes sense for `t.join()` to immediately follow `t.start()`.