# Tkinter loop issues

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I'll start with an apology for my lack of knowledge/ignorance.

In brief I wish to create a clocking system for employees. Scan an RFID card and it logs a timestamp.
Found this https://www.hackster.io/sarful/how-to-build-a-raspberry-pi-rfid-attendance-system-dcb834#code

this works great, but it only uses terminal.  I wish to jazz it up with an app using Tkinter - adding a company logo, current time/date.

the second block of code is what i have come up with.

When I run it no window appears with logo, clock it just runs like original code in terminal without tkinter parts.
If I comment out the original and leave the tkinter part, my window with the logo and clock appears.

There is probably a simple explanation and fix for this, but when I research into it I just get more and more confused.

Please could you lovely, kind and knowledgeable people tell me exactly the issue and how to fix it.
Many thanks in advance.

Original code

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="username",
  passwd="password",
  database="attendance_system"
)

cursor = db.cursor()
reader = SimpleMFRC522()

try:
  while True:
    print('Scan Card to\nrecord clocking')
    id, text = reader.read()

    cursor.execute("Select id, name FROM users WHERE rfid_uid="+str(id))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if cursor.rowcount >= 1:
      print(result[1] + "\nClocking confirmed")
      time.sleep(2)
      cursor.execute("INSERT INTO clockings (name) VALUES (%s)", (result[1],) )
      db.commit()
    else:
        print("User does not exist.")
        time.sleep(2)
finally:
  GPIO.cleanup()
```

Original with my tkinter code.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="username",
  passwd="password",
  database="attendance_system"
)

cursor = db.cursor()
reader = SimpleMFRC522()

root = Tk()
root.title('Clocking System')
root.geometry("128x128")
root.configure(bg='white')

my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Logo.png"))
my_label = Label(image=my_img)
my_label.pack()

def clock():
    hour = time.strftime("%H")
    minute = time.strftime("%M")
    second = time.strftime("%S")
    day = time.strftime("%a")
    date = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

    my_label.config(text=hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second)
    my_label.after(1000, clock)

    my_label2.config(text=day + " " + date)

def update():
    my_label.config(text="")

my_label = Label(root, text="", font=("Helvetica", 20), fg="black", bg="white")
my_label.pack()#(pady=20)
my_label2 = Label(root, text="", font=("Helvetica", 10), fg="black", bg="white")
my_label2.pack()#(pady=20)
my_label3 = Label(root, text="", font=("Helvetica", 20), fg="black", bg="white")
my_label3.pack()#(pady=20)

clock()

try:
  while True:
    print('Scan Card to\nrecord clocking')
    my_label3.config(text="Scan Card to record clocking")
    id, text = reader.read()

    cursor.execute("Select id, name FROM users WHERE rfid_uid="+str(id))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if cursor.rowcount >= 1:
      print(result[1] + "\nClocking confirmed")
      my_label3.config(text=result[1] + " Clocking confirmed")
      time.sleep(2)
      cursor.execute("INSERT INTO clockings (name) VALUES (%s)", (result[1],) )
      db.commit()
    else:
        print("User does not exist.")
        my_label3.config(text="User does not exist.")
        time.sleep(2)
finally:
  GPIO.cleanup()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are going to have to use a different approach to get this working with a GUI. The line: `id, text = reader.read()` will block and this (combined with the `while`) will stop the code ever reaching `root.mainloop()`. I think you may need to use a thread to run the card reader and post requests back to the main thread so it can modify the GUI upon request.

Comment: See my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59327160/what-techniques-are-there-to-allow-multiple-threads-in-a-tkinter-program)

Comment: ok - not a simple fix then? or is it? would you be willing to help? please!!

Comment: I’ll look at it tomorrow.

Comment: It will need the while loop encapsulated in a function, which will be called in a thread. It will need some more functions to operate the GUI, and a queue and message pump to take requests from the thread back to the main thread.

Comment: You are a star!!  Thanks much appreciated. I will have a read and try to understand in the meantime.

Comment: sorted it - thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Sorted it - thanks for your help

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522
import mysql.connector
import threading

db = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="username",
  passwd="password",
  database="attendance_system"
)

cursor = db.cursor()
reader = SimpleMFRC522()

root = Tk()
root.title('Clocking System')
root.geometry("128x128")
root.configure(bg='white')

my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Logo.png"))
my_label = Label(image=my_img)
my_label.pack()

def clock():
    hour = time.strftime("%H")
    minute = time.strftime("%M")
    second = time.strftime("%S")
    day = time.strftime("%a")
    date = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

    my_label.config(text=hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second)
    my_label.after(1000, clock)

    my_label2.config(text=day + " " + date)

my_label = Label(root, text="", font=("Helvetica", 40), fg="black", bg="white")
my_label.pack()#(pady=20)
my_label2 = Label(root, text="", font=("Helvetica", 10), fg="black", bg="white")
my_label2.pack()#(pady=20)
my_label3 = Label(root, text="", font=("Helvetica", 20), fg="black", bg="white")
my_label3.pack()#(pady=20)


def clockings():
    
    try:
      while True:
        print('Scan Card to\nrecord clocking')
        my_label3.config(text="Scan Card to record clocking")
        id, text = reader.read()

        cursor.execute("Select id, name FROM users WHERE rfid_uid="+str(id))
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        if cursor.rowcount >= 1:
          print(result[1] + "\nClocking confirmed")
          my_label3.config(text=result[1] + " Clocking confirmed")
          time.sleep(2)
          cursor.execute("INSERT INTO clockings (name) VALUES (%s)", (result[1],) )
          db.commit()
        else:
            print("User does not exist.")
            my_label3.config(text="User does not exist.")
            time.sleep(2)
    finally:
      GPIO.cleanup()

threading.Thread(target=clockings).start()

clock()

root.mainloop()
```