# Change tkinter label value with function inside a process using multiprocessing

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multiprocessing

I want to do something like this. Call a function from inside of one of the processes, and change the value of a label:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from tkinter import DISABLED, NORMAL, Label, LabelFrame, Tk

def process1():
    print("Executing process1")
    #doSomething

def process2():
    print("Executing process2")
    show_active_process()

def startProcesses():
    global p1
    global p2
    p1 = mp.Process(target = process1)
    p2 = mp.Process(target = process2)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()

def stopProcesses():
    p1.terminate()
    p2.terminate()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':

    def show_active_process():
        currentUserProcess2.configure(text="Executing process 2")
    
    root = Tk()

    p1 = mp.Process(target = process1)
    p2 = mp.Process(target = process2)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    
    root.geometry('150x100')

    frameP1 = LabelFrame(root, text="Process1", font=("Helvetica", 14, "bold"), bd=0)
    frameP1.pack(padx=12)
    currentUserProcess1 = Label(frameP1, text="Current User p1", font=("Helvetica", 10, "bold"))
    currentUserProcess1.pack()
    
    frameP2 = LabelFrame(root, text="Process2", font=("Helvetica", 14, "bold"), bd=0)
    frameP2.pack()
    currentUserProcess2 = Label(frameP2, text="Current User p2", font=("Helvetica", 10, "bold"))
    currentUserProcess2.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

But I get this error:

> NameError: name 'show_active_process' is not defined

It should be changing the default label value from "Current User process p2" to "Executing process 2"

I've tried using Queue but I couldn't make it work. Also I'm not sharing data across processes here so I don't know if it's necessary to use that.

I think there must be a simple way to do this, but I couldn't find an answer that work for me yet.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You will need a `Queue`, like I use in my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59327160/what-techniques-are-there-to-allow-multiple-threads-in-a-tkinter-program), but one that can only pass data through. You can use some sort of mapping to map the data to actions that the main thread can execute, like calling `show_active_process()`

Comment: Oh I see. When you say main thread do you mean one of the processes? I count 3. "process1", "process2" and tkinter. Is that correct?

Comment: Its usual to run `tkinter` in the main thread and start other threads or processes to do other independent work. However *anything* that touches anything to do with `tkinter` has to be executed by the main thread, say in a timer event or button press event that `tkinter` has control over.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def show_active_process():
```

isn't defined in the scope of

```py
def process2():
```

You can change the label value without using a separate process. I would recommend completely eliminating those separate processes from your code and simplifying it to just Tkinter's main loop.

Comment: The thing is that I need two different process because each one will be doing something different at the same time, and I need to show if a process is running or not in the GUI

Comment: What you need to do is add currentUserProcess2 into the scope of process2() so that you can change it within the function. Since I don't know what you're going to be doing with those processes I can't help you much from there, but I think that should be enough to get you thinking about how to solve your problem.

Comment: I tried using global scope for currentUserProcess2, and changing the order of the functions in order to avoid Not defined error, but I get 
`AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'process2' on <module '__mp_main__'`

Comment: Without more information on what the processes do there's not much more I can recommend.

Comment: The two processes check a group of folders in a loop. Depending on what name the folder has, one of the process gets executed and does something with the files inside the folder. I want to show in the GUI when a process is running or not. I hope I explained myself. Maybe there is a simpler way to achieve that.