# How to avoid problems with tkinters mainloop when integrating client/server communication for a python tkinter game using sockets and threading?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, sockets, tkinter

I am a self proclaimed intermediate/hobby python programmer and my latest passion project has been replicating the board game Catan using python and the GUI library tkinter. I've spent the better part of 3 weeks now trying to figure out how to implement the client/server communication which should keep the game synced between all players. I'm using sockets and threading for this and I need the server to initiate some user input/actions from a client, the client to send what they did back to the server, and then the server to send that back to all other clients to update their GUI. Googling/youtube videos/AI chatbots have only gotten me so far in the past three weeks so I figured I would ask here.

The main problem that I have deduced I have is that the tkinter mainloop() has to run to update the GUI but I have also been trying to use a separate while loop to check for messages on the client. I've heard that maybe tkinter and sockets should never be used together and other things but I'm thinking that I just don't have my code organized correctly and/or I need to change the scope of where I define things. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Here is the relevant client code

```
#Happens once when the client first connects
clientPlayerName = input("Enter your name: ")
clientColor = input("What colour would you like to be? ")

sendToServer("[New Player Incoming]") #tells the server that a new player name and colour are coming
sendToServer(clientPlayerName)
sendToServer(clientColor)
#********************************************************************


while True:
    msg = recieveFromServer()
    if msg == "START GAME":
        print(playerObj.name)
        game_starting = True
        players_list = recieveFromServer()
        game = displayGUI(playerObj) #displayGui returns the initialized game object. displayGUI also starts the tkinter mainloop
        print("test")
        break

    elif msg == "PLAYER OBJECT INCOMING": #gets the player object from the server based on name and colour entered when client connected
        playerObj = recieveFromServer()


while game_starting:
    msg = recieveFromServer()
    turn = None
    if msg == "NEW TURN":
        turn = recieveFromServer()
    changeLabel(f"{turn.name}'s turn")

    if turn == playerObj: #if its this clients turn, let them place their objects
        placed_objects = placeStartingThing(game.grid, playerObj)#returns the made objects as (settlement, road)

        sendToServer("OBJECTS INCOMING")
        sendToServer(placed_objects) #{settlement: position num, road: (start_pos num, end_pos num)}


    elif msg == "OBJECTS COMING FROM SERVER": #places new objects that were placed by another client from the dictionary sent by the server
        objects_to_place = recieveFromServer()
        placeSettlement(game.grid, playerObj, objects_to_place["settlement"])
        placeRoad(game.grid, playerObj, objects_to_place["road"][0], objects_to_place["road"][1])

    elif msg == "START OF GAME COMPLETE":
        game_starting = False
```

---

And the code for the actual game:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time
from math import sqrt, sin, cos, tan, radians


#This class is only used by the server code to make new player objects when a new client joins
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, colour):
        self.colour = colour
        self.name = name
        self.owned_hexagons = []
        self.resources = {"wheat" : 0, "ore" : 0, "sheep" : 0, "wood" : 0, "brick" : 0}
        self.victoryPoints = 0
        self.owned_positions = []



class Hexagon:
    def __init__(self, canvas, length, startx, starty, colour):
        self.length = length
        self.startx = startx
        self.starty = starty
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.colour = colour
        self.corners = []
        self.corner6 = []    #variable containing coordinates for the top left corner (starting position) of any hexagon
        self.dice_number = None
        self.resource = None
        
        self.getResource()
        self.draw()
        
    def draw(self):
        startx = self.startx
        starty = self.starty
        angle = 60
        coords = []
        for i in range(6):
            end_x = startx + self.length * sin(radians(angle * i))  #calculates the next vertex of the hexagon 6 times and puts it into the coords list as a two unit list. 
            end_y = starty + self.length * cos(radians(angle * i))  #starts at the vertex to the left of the top and moves around counter-clockwise
            coords.append([startx, starty])
            startx = end_x
            starty = end_y
        self.canvas.create_polygon(coords[0][0],
                                coords[0][1], 
                                coords[1][0], 
                                coords[1][1],
                                coords[2][0],
                                coords[2][1],
                                coords[3][0],
                                coords[3][1],
                                coords[4][0],
                                coords[4][1], 
                                coords[5][0],
                                coords[5][1], 
                                fill=self.colour)
        self.corners = [coords[5], coords[4], coords[3], coords[2], coords[1], coords[0]] #puts the vertexes into self.corners starting from the top one and going clockwise
        self.corner6 = self.corners[5]

    def getCenter(self):
        center = [self.corner6[0] + (self.length / (tan(radians(30))))/2, self.corner6[1] + self.length/2]
        return center

    def getResource(self):
        if self.colour == "coral3":
            self.resource = "brick"
        elif self.colour == "gold":
            self.resource = "wheat"
        elif self.colour == "gray35":
            self.resource = "ore"
        elif self.colour == "dark green":
            self.resource = "wood"
        elif self.colour == "spring green":
            self.resource = "sheep"
        else:
            self.resource = "desert"

class Grid():
    #static variables
    hexdict = {} #dictionary to contain each hexagon object and its number

    def __init__(self, side_length):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("Catan")
        self.root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, width=900, height=900)
        self.canvas.pack()
        
        self.side_length = side_length
        self.interval = self.side_length / (tan(radians(30))) + 5 #spacing between tiles, their width plus a spacing of 5 pixels
        self.starting_x = 450 - self.interval * 1.5 #calculates these from the side length so the board is always centered
        self.starting_y = 450 - (3.5*self.side_length)
        self.colours = ["coral3", "coral3", "coral3",
                        "gold", "gold", "gold", "gold",
                        "gray35","gray35","gray35", "wheat1",
                        "dark green","dark green","dark green","dark green",
                        "spring green", "spring green", "spring green", "spring green"]
        random.shuffle(self.colours)
        self.dice_numbers = [2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12]
        random.shuffle(self.dice_numbers)
        self.count = 0 #counter for the number of hexagons
        self.road_positions = []

        self.makeGrid()
        self.addNumbers()

    def makeRow(self, start_pos, amount):
        for c in range(amount):                 #makes the specified number of hexagons the correct distance apart using the interval value plus a spacing of 5
            h = Hexagon(self.canvas, self.side_length, start_pos[0] + self.interval*c, start_pos[1], self.colours[0])
            del self.colours[0]
            self.count = self.count + 1
            Grid.hexdict.update({self.count : h}) #adds each new hexagon object to the dictionary with the key being its number
            

    def makeGrid(self):
        row_pos = [self.starting_x, self.starting_y] #starting position calculated in __init__
        self.makeRow(row_pos, 3)
        row_pos = [self.starting_x - (self.interval/2), self.starting_y + (self.side_length * 1.5) + 3.5]  #offsetting the starting position of the next row before building the next row. 
        self.makeRow(row_pos, 4)
        row_pos = [row_pos[0] - (self.interval/2), row_pos[1] + (self.side_length * 1.5) + 3.5]
        self.makeRow(row_pos, 5)
        row_pos = [row_pos[0] + (self.interval/2), row_pos[1] + (self.side_length * 1.5) + 3.5]
        self.makeRow(row_pos, 4)
        row_pos = [row_pos[0] + (self.interval/2), row_pos[1] + (self.side_length * 1.5) + 3.5]
        self.makeRow(row_pos, 3)

    def addNumbers(self): #adds numbers to each hexagon in the grid as their dice roll value
        for h in range(19):
            if Grid.hexdict[h+1].colour != "wheat1":#for all tiles except the desert, add the next number from list of dice rolls to the middle of the tile and delete the number used 
                self.canvas.create_text(Grid.hexdict[h+1].getCenter()[0], Grid.hexdict[h+1].getCenter()[1], text = self.dice_numbers[0], font=('Roboto 24 bold'))
                Grid.hexdict[h+1].dice_number = self.dice_numbers[0] #assign the dice number just put onto text to the hexagons dice_number object variable
                del self.dice_numbers[0] #delete the number just used from the list so it goes to the next one


global settlementPositionsDict
settlementPositionsDict = {}
class SettlementPosition(Grid):
    #static variables
    positionsTuple = ([1,5], [1,0], [1,1], [2,0], [2,1], [3,0], [3,1], [4,5], [1,4], [1,3], [1,2], [2,3], [2,2], [3,3], [3,2], [7,1], [8,5], [4,4], [4,3], [4,2], [5,3], [5,2], [6,3],
        [6,2], [7,3], [7,2], [12,1], [8,4], [8,3], [8,2], [9,3], [9,2], [10,3], [10,2], [11,3], [11,2], [12,3], [12,2], [13,4], [13,3], [13,2], [14,3], [14,2], [15,3], [15,2],
        [16,3], [16,2], [17,4], [17,3], [17,2], [18,3], [18,2], [19,3], [19,2]) #contains the hexagon and its corner for each settlement position

    def __init__(self, number, coordinates):
        self.number = number
        self.coordinates = coordinates #[x, y]
        #dictionary element with a number 1-54 for key and containing the type of building there[0], the coordinates[1] the player[2], the settlement position object itself[3],
        #its number[4] (1-54), and the object built there[5] either City or Settlement.
        settlementPositionsDict[self.number] = [None, self.coordinates, None, self, self.number, None]

        

    def getSettlementCenter(self): #returns an [x, y] coordinate of the center of a settlement
        settlementCenter = self.coordinates
        return settlementCenter

    def distanceBetween(self, other):#called by a settlement position object and takes another settlementPosition object as a parameter to compare it to
        #returns the distance between the object calling and the parameter object as a float
        return sqrt(pow(self.coordinates[0] - other.coordinates[0], 2) + pow(self.coordinates[1] - other.coordinates[1], 2))
    def getAdjacentSettlementPositions(self):
        self.adjacentPositions = []
        for key in settlementPositionsDict: #for every settlement position
            if self.distanceBetween(settlementPositionsDict[key][3]) < 90 and self.distanceBetween(settlementPositionsDict[key][3]) > 5: #if the distance between the object calling the method and the object passed by the for loop is close
                self.adjacentPositions.append(settlementPositionsDict[key][3])
            if len(self.adjacentPositions) >= 3:
                break

        #makes 54 settlementPosition objects with the location of the correct hexagon corner taken from the tuple above.
    @staticmethod 
    def initializeObjects():
        for s in range(54):
            settlementposition = SettlementPosition(s+1, Grid.hexdict[SettlementPosition.positionsTuple[s][0]].corners[SettlementPosition.positionsTuple[s][1]])




#****************************************************************************************************************************************************

class Settlement():
    def __init__(self, canvas, settlementPositionObject, player): #takes an element of the settlementPositionsDict as a parameter
        if settlementPositionObject[0] == None:
            self.canvas = canvas
            self.settlementPositionObject = settlementPositionObject
            self.location = settlementPositionObject[1] #gets the actual location of the settlement from the settlementPosition object's index[1]
            self.end_location = (self.location[0] + 30, self.location[1] + 20) #change size of settlement here
            self.player = player
            self.colour = self.player.colour
            self.adjacents = []
        
            self.settlementPositionObject[0] = "Settlement" #Updating elements of the settlementPositionsDict entry when a new settlement is initialized.
            self.settlementPositionObject[2] = self.player
            self.settlementPositionObject[5] = self

            self.player.owned_positions.append(self.settlementPositionObject[3])
            self.player.victoryPoints += 1

        
            self.draw()
            self.player.owned_hexagons.extend(self.getAdjacents()) #during settlement init, adds the adjacent hexagons to the settlement to the list of players owned hexagons


        
    def draw(self):     #takes the x and y from both corners of the rectangle (location and end_location) and offsets them to the middle of the junction.
        self.rectangle = self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.location[0] - 15, self.location[1] - 10, self.end_location[0] - 15, self.end_location[1] - 10,
                                    fill=self.colour, outline="light gray", tags=self.settlementPositionObject[4])
        #makes an object variable containing the rectangle of the settlement

    def getAdjacents(self):
        self.adjacents = []
        for key in Grid.hexdict: #for every hexagon
            for c in range(6):      #for each corner
                if abs(Grid.hexdict[key].corners[c][0] - self.location[0]) < 20 and abs(Grid.hexdict[key].corners[c][1] - self.location[1]) < 20: #if the settlement is on that tile
                    self.adjacents.append(Grid.hexdict[key]) #append that hexagon to the list of the settlements adjacent hexagons
        return self.adjacents

#**********************************************************************************************************

class Road():
    roadsList = []
    def __init__(self, canvas, start_position_object, end_position_object, player): #location takes two settlement position objects and draw a thick line in between them. 
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.player = player
        self.start_position_object = start_position_object
        self.end_position_object = end_position_object
        self.start_location = start_position_object.getSettlementCenter() #converts the settlement position objects to their actual coordinates
        self.end_location = end_position_object.getSettlementCenter()

        self.player.owned_positions.append(start_position_object)
        self.player.owned_positions.append(end_position_object)

        Road.roadsList.append([self.start_location, self.end_location]) #adds an [x, y] of the new road to the roadsList list

        self.draw()

    def getRoadDistance(self): #returns the distance between the two points of the road
        return sqrt(pow(self.start_location[0] - self.end_location[0], 2) + pow(self.start_location[1] - self.end_location[1], 2))
        
    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.create_line(self.start_location, self.end_location, fill=self.player.colour, width=5)

#****************************************************************************************************************

class City():
    def __init__(self, canvas, replacedSettlement, player): #takes a settlement object as the replacedSettlement parameter
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.player = player
        self.length = 40        #if the first dectionary element of the settlement position object of the settlement object being replaced is a settlement, and if its the same player
        if replacedSettlement.settlementPositionObject[0] == "Settlement" and replacedSettlement.settlementPositionObject[2] == self.player:
            self.settlementPositionObject = replacedSettlement.settlementPositionObject     #make the cities settlementPositionObject the same as the replaced settlements one
            self.location = self.settlementPositionObject[1]    #set the location object variable to the location of the settlementPositionObject
        
            self.draw(self.length, self.location)   

            self.canvas.delete(replacedSettlement.rectangle) #delete the rectangle of the settlement
        

    def draw(self, length, middle):
        top = [middle[0], middle[1] - (length * cos(radians(30)))/2]
        botRight = [middle[0] + (length/2), middle[1] + (length * cos(radians(30)))/2]
        botLeft = [middle[0] - (length/2), middle[1] + (length * cos(radians(30)))/2]

        self.canvas.create_polygon(top[0], top[1], botRight[0], botRight[1], botLeft[0], botLeft[1], fill=self.player.colour, outline="light gray")





    #*******************************************************************
                    
def validSettlement(positionChecked):#takes a settlementPosition object as its parameter and raises an exception if bad settlement position
    positionChecked.getAdjacentSettlementPositions()
    if positionChecked.number < 55 and positionChecked.number > 0 and settlementPositionsDict[positionChecked.number][0] == None: #if its on the board and the spot is empty
        for positions in positionChecked.adjacentPositions: #for all adjacent settlementPositionObjects
            if settlementPositionsDict[positions.number][0] != None: #if the current position is not empty
                raise Exception("Womp Womp")
    else:
        raise Exception("Womp Womp")

def validRoad(pos1, pos2, player): #both parameters are numbers from 1-54
    settleObjPos1 = settlementPositionsDict[pos1][3] #these are just to save typing and space and represent the settlement position objects of each pos1 and pos2
    settleObjPos2 = settlementPositionsDict[pos2][3]

    road_exists = False
    for road in Road.roadsList:
        if settleObjPos1.coordinates == road[0] and settleObjPos2.coordinates == road[1]:
            road_exists = True
    
    if pos1 < 55 and pos1 > 0 and pos2 < 55 and pos2 > 0: #if both points are on the board
        if settleObjPos1.distanceBetween(settleObjPos2) < 85 and settleObjPos1.distanceBetween(settleObjPos2) > 5: #if the two road points are actually next to each other
            if settleObjPos1 in player.owned_positions or settleObjPos2 in player.owned_positions: #if the road is connected to something already built
                if not road_exists:
                    pass
                else:
                    raise Exception("Womp Womp")
            else:
                raise Exception("Womp Womp")
            
        else:
            raise Exception("Womp Womp")
    else:
        raise Exception("Womp Womp")


#********************************************************************************************************
def buttonInit(grid):
    global settlementPositionsDict
    global settlementNumbersList
    settlementNumbersList= []       #Toggling settlement numbers 
    global settlementNumbers
    settlementNumbers = False
    def toggleSettlementNumbers(settlementPositionsDict):
        global settlementNumbers
        if settlementNumbers == True:
            settlementNumbers = False
            settlementNumbersOff()
        elif settlementNumbers == False:
            settlementNumbersOn(settlementPositionsDict)
            settlementNumbers = True   
    def settlementNumbersOn(settlementPositionsDict):
        global settlementNumbersList
        settlementNumbersList = []
        for a in range(54):
            settlementNumbersList.append(
                grid.canvas.create_text(settlementPositionsDict[a + 1][1][0], settlementPositionsDict[a + 1][1][1], text=a+1, font="Roboto 14",))      
    def settlementNumbersOff():
        for a in range(54):
            grid.canvas.delete(settlementNumbersList[a])

    grid.toggleSettlementNumbersButton = Button(grid.root, text="Toggle Settlement Numbers", font="Roboto, 10", bg="steel blue", activebackground="sky blue", command=lambda: toggleSettlementNumbers(settlementPositionsDict))
    grid.toggleSettlementNumbersButton.place(x=50, y=800) #makes these btn variables object variables of the grid

    grid.quitBtn = Button(grid.root, text="Quit", bg="steel blue", activebackground="sky blue", command=lambda: (grid.root.destroy()))
    grid.quitBtn.place(x=445, y=800)

    global textInput
    textInput = None
    global clickCheck
    clickCheck = IntVar() #boolean that says if the program is waiting for input into the field or not

    field = Entry(grid.root)    #creates a text entry field and stores the contents in the textInput variable when the button is pressed.
    field.place(x=700, y=50)
    field.focus_set()

    def getInput():
        global textInput
        textInput = field.get()
        field.delete(0, END)
        clickCheck.set(1)
    
    grid.enterButton = Button(grid.root, text="Enter", font="Helvetica, 10", bg="steel blue", activebackground="sky blue", fg="white", command=getInput)
    grid.enterButton.place(x=700, y=75)

    global mainLabel
    mainLabel = Label(grid.root, bg="pink", text="Welcome to Catan!", font="Helvetica, 12")
    mainLabel.place(relx = 0.5, y=50, anchor = CENTER)


def changeLabel(text):
    mainLabel.config(text=text)



class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.grid = Grid(75)
        SettlementPosition.initializeObjects()


def displayGUI(playerObj):
    game = Main()
    buttonInit(game.grid)
    Label(game.grid.root, text=playerObj.name, font="Helvetica, 9", bg="steel blue").pack(anchor="se")
    game.grid.root.mainloop()

    return game

def placeStartingThing(grid, player):
    placing = True
    changeLabel(player.name + ", place your first settlement. \n(Enter the number.)")
    while placing:
        grid.enterButton.wait_variable(clickCheck)
        try:
            validSettlement(settlementPositionsDict[int(textInput)][3])
            settlement = Settlement(grid.canvas, settlementPositionsDict[int(textInput)], player)
            changeLabel("Now place a road. \n(Enter a number coming off the settlement.)")
            placing = False
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            changeLabel("Enter a valid settlement position number.")

    sp = int(textInput) #stores the number of the settlementPosition of the settlement just placed to use for building the road
    while not placing:
        grid.enterButton.wait_variable(clickCheck)
        try:
            validRoad(sp, int(textInput), player)
            road = Road(grid.canvas, settlementPositionsDict[sp][3], settlementPositionsDict[int(textInput)][3], player)
            placing = True
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            changeLabel("Enter a valid road location \n(You only have 3 options you can't mess this up)")
    changeLabel("Success")

    return {"settlement": settlement.settlementPositionObject[4], "road": (settlementPositionsDict[sp][4], settlementPositionsDict[int(textInput)][4])}
    #returns the settlements (position object number) and the roads (start object position number, end object position number) 1-54


def placeSettlement(grid, player, position):
    try:
        validSettlement(settlementPositionsDict[position][1])
        settlement = Settlement(grid.canvas, settlementPositionsDict[position][1], player)
    except:
        pass

def placeRoad(grid, player, start_pos, end_pos):
    try:
        validRoad(start_pos, end_pos)
        road = Road(grid.canvas, settlementPositionsDict[start_pos][3], settlementPositionsDict[end_pos][3], player)
    except:
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Ben = Player("Ben", "green")
    displayGUI(Ben)
    placeStartingThing(displayGUI)
```

Also I know my code probably isnt the best but once again this is purely for my own enjoyment so.

Comment: You have way too much code there. I can only give general advice like: look into [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) and [`after` loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25753719/11106801). It's best to avoid using calling `tkinter` methods from other threads so use queues like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53697547/11106801) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59327161/11106801)

Answer (score 0):

as a learner you should know that using loops in a tkinter program will freeze the GUI because the `mainloop()` function of tkinter is itself a loop, and running another loop within it can create conflicts. To avoid this you can simply use the `.after()` function, since your code is too long heres a small snippet to get you show you the trick:

```
def recieve_from_server(): # created an example function instead of while True
    msg = recieveFromServer()
    if msg == "START GAME":
        print(playerObj.name)
        game_starting = True
        players_list = recieveFromServer()
        game = displayGUI(playerObj) #displayGui returns the initialized game object. displayGUI also starts the tkinter mainloop
        print("test")
        break

    elif msg == "PLAYER OBJECT INCOMING": #gets the player object from the server based on name and colour entered when client connected
        playerObj = recieveFromServer()
        root.after(1000, recieve_from_server)

recieve_from_server()
```

This run the function after every second reducing the `1000` from the `root.after(1000, recieve_from_server)` line will reduce the time of function repeating.

Lemme know if u need help with anything else.

Comment: `root.after(1000, recieve_from_server())` is equivalent to `recieve_from_server(); sleep(1)`. You probably wanted `root.after(1000, recieve_from_server)` instead which schedules a call to `recieve_from_server` for 1000 millisecond in the future. Also that depends on how `recieveFromServer()` is implemented (blocking vs non-blocking)

Comment: @TheLizzard you are right indeed, also after you made that comment I noticed an error in my commad lemme just edit it real quick.

Comment: Ahh okay yeah I was completely unaware of the after() function which goes to show how little experience I have. Thanks for the answer! I'll try to implement that.